# Find LP token for a pair using UniswapV3

Tags: uniswap

From Uniswap docs:

```
   function getPool(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint24 fee
  ) external view returns (address pool)
```

What does the "fee" parameter means? and how do you calculate it?

Can I find an LP token for a pair if the fee is unknown?

Answer (score 0):

Each Uniswap pool can define its own fee that goes to the liquidity providers from every transaction.

In Uniswap v2 the fee was hardcoded to 0.30%. In Uniswap v3 it is configurable.

For example, deep, high liquid and active pools like ETH-USDC have pool versions where the fee is 0.05% instead of the standard 0.30%.